# Displaying only limited values in texBox winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am displaying temperature of type float in textBox which keeps on updating every 15 seconds .Currently textBox shows every updated temperature value but I want textBox to display only last three values of updated temperature thus if temperature is updated for fourth time the textBox should discard last temperature and should show only three temperature values. Is their any way for achieving this? I am using following code for displaying temperature:-

```
  textBox.AppendText("\r\n" + temp);
```

Comment: Please post your complete code.

Comment: I think I am using only this code for displaying temperature in textBox. Every time I get new temperature value I use this code to display temperature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
string[] temp = {"0","1","2"};
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                temp[i] = Convert.ToString( i + ",");
                textBox1.AppendText("\r\n" + temp[i]);
            }
```

Comment: This code makes me confused. `temp[i]` seems to do nothing, it's just a `temp` string. Unless you use `temp` array somewhere out of this code, otherwise it's for nothing, it's just simpler by doing this `textBox1.AppendText("\r\n" + i + ",");`?